# Can I use PHP to select base on Case and If?

Tags: php

In my database I have entires which have a Key called 'status' and they have a non-numerical value (such A, B, Q)

I want to use a PHP script to echo something different depending on the value

Right now my page just selects the value of the key.

Edit:

Sorry guys. I have tried this:

```
while( $notify = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet) ) { 
    echo '</td><td>'.$notify['status'].'</td></tr>'; 
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried already?

Comment: If you post some code how it selects the key, we can modify it and get the if in place. Else we'll post some general code, but it'll benefit you less... the more you post, the more we can help.

Comment: Sorry guys. I have tried this 
 while($notify=mysql_fetch_array($resultSet))
                { 
                    echo '</td><td>'.$notify['status'].'</td></tr>';
                    
                            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to @Andre's solution, you can also do the transform directly in SQL:

```
SELECT CASE status WHEN 'A' THEN 'Approved'
                   WHEN 'B' THEN 'Basic'
                   WHEN 'Q' THEN 'Questionable'
                   ELSE 'Other'
       END AS status_word
FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
while( $notify = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet) ) { 
    var $output = '</td><td>'; 

    switch( $notify['status'] )
    {
        case "A":
            $output += 'The status is A';
            break;
        case "B":
            $output += 'The status is B';
            break;
        case "Q":
            $output += 'The status is Q';
            break;
        default:
            $output += 'The status is ' .$notify['status'];
            break;
    }
    $output += '</td></tr>'; 
    echo $output;
}
```

Of course, with different output on each case...